# Mount command not found in windows

Tags: windows-10, command-line, mount, nfs

Part of the instructions I'm following indicates (https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/) typing `mount -o anon \\server_ip_address\mnt\vms` in windows command prompt. In cygwing, the command is not recognized but not with the option `anon`

But I get the following error: `'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Professional? And did you install the Client for NFS feature?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise. The only thing I tried is mapping a network drive but it didn't seem to work for me!

Comment: Did you install the Client for NFS feature?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that. Can you explain? I'm totally new to this.

Comment: As per the link you posted in your question, you need to install the Client for NFS Windows Feature from add/remove features.

Comment: My bad. Yes I sure did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a path issue.

In a command prompt `cd\` to go back to the root, then `dir/s mount.exe`.

This should come back with 1 or more hits, and in my case the path is

> C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-nfs-clientcmdtools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_36e3ef7a599c9380

If you then `cd` to that directory, you should be able to run `mount` from there.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.I guess I'm not so familiar with windows command prompt :/